# Animated css/js waves do not resize with window size

Tags: javascript, css, animation, overflow

I'm trying to create a full viewport size header with animated waves (yes, water waves) using css & javascript. Everything is fine except for the collective width of the waves not resizing with the width of the window, even in the codepen example I got the snippets from it doesn't resize.

There's also an overflow problem with it; Each light blue bar is 10px (from what I understand in the js) and upon page reload there is always 1 too many bars, creating a horizontal scrollbar. I've tried hiding the overflows but it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm assuming it has to be controlled through the js, but I'm just not too familiar with javascript yet to make a fix.

Anyone have any ideas?

Here's the codepen link: https://codepen.io/loktar00/pen/kfrKC

And the javascript:

```
var ocean = document.getElementById("ocean"),
waveWidth = 10,
waveCount = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/waveWidth),
docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(var i = 0; i < waveCount; i++){
var wave = document.createElement("div");
wave.className += " wave";
docFrag.appendChild(wave);
wave.style.left = i * waveWidth + "px";
wave.style.webkitAnimationDelay = (i/100) + "s";}

ocean.appendChild(docFrag);
```

edit: just wanted to make it clear the codepen snippet isnt mine, couldnt find the author

Comment: That's really cool Tyler :)

Comment: You can try: place all that code in a function and use `$(window).resize(yourFunction);`

Comment: Changing 100 to 200 makes it flow better @ webkitAnimationDelay. Could you post a screenshot of the scrollbar you're getting? add `overflow: hidden;` to `body`

Comment: overflow: hidden; 
works well, but it also disables vertical scrolling, so the user cant scroll to the bottom of the "ocean" or to the content.

I tried overflow-x: hidden; but that doesn't help either

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
var myFunc = function() {
// make some waves.
var ocean = document.getElementById("ocean"),
    waveWidth = 10,
    waveCount = Math.floor(window.innerWidth/waveWidth),
    docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for(var i = 0; i < waveCount; i++){
  var wave = document.createElement("div");
  wave.className += " wave";
  docFrag.appendChild(wave);
  wave.style.left = i * waveWidth + "px";
  wave.style.webkitAnimationDelay = (i/100) + "s";
}

ocean.appendChild(docFrag);

}
myFunc();
$(window).resize(myFunc);
```

To eliminate the scrollbars use `overflow: hidden;` for `body`

Comment: hmm i didn't see a difference, heres a screenshot of the problem:

http://i182.photobucket.com/albums/x19/nbslyer10/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-06%20at%201.45.55%20AM_zpswxqgu5ua.png

edit: cleaned up link

Comment: Why doesn't `overflow: hidden` fix it? post a screen with it

Comment: heres with overflow hidden: http://tinyurl.com/q4pb8of
and heres with no overflow property: http://tinyurl.com/pdkmo45

Comment: Weird, on 1 screenshot I see a list items and on the other I don't. in any case, it seems like `overflow:hidden` fixed the problem of hiding the scroll bar.

Comment: on the first screenshot i cant scroll down to see the items because of the hidden overflow, but on the second one without the overflow property it lets me scroll to the content as normal- only theres still that horizontal scrollbar =/

Comment: then use `overflow-y: hidden`... and by the way, the original code you posted doesn't contain any list items...

Comment: overflow-y: hidden; does get rid of the scroll bar but it doesn't fix the problem with the wave upon resizing the window. If you size the window smaller then back up, the wave remains the smaller size =/